# Does the 4-vector gradient commute with "itself"? If yes, why do they commute?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Does $[\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}] = 0$? If yes, why do they commute?

Comment: Yes, it does commute, at least in the context of quantum field theory (i'm not familiar with GR).

Comment: @ColourfulSpacetime thank you, how does one justify (or prove) that? Is it just by inspection since a 4-gradient does not operate on anything and can hardly mean something by itself or is it an analysis argument of "order of differentiation does not matter"?

Comment: I have no idea!  Hopefully someone with more technical background can answer this.  I would suggest you also edit your question to add something like ''If yes, why do they commute?''

Comment: @ColourfulSpacetime same, great idea!

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: Partial derivatives commute; covariant ones don't. The latter fact is integral to parallel transport.

Answer (score 1):

For a smooth scalar functions $f$ (which are the objects on which the vector fields $\partial_\mu$ are defined to act), we simply have that
$$[\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu]f=\partial_\mu\partial_\nu f -\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f= 0$$
because of the equality of mixed partial derivatives from elementary analysis. Because $f$ is arbitrary, $[\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu]$ (which is itself a vector field) is the vector field which eats a scalar function and spits out zero - i.e. it is the zero vector field.

Comment: Here is the relevant wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: Basically, the function needs to be $C^2$ in order for second order partial derivatives to commute.  I comment on that because usually ''smooth'' functions refer to $C^{\infty}$ functions, which is a stronger condition.

Comment: @ColourfulSpacetime [Conventions vary](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html). You're right that a function doesn't need to be $C^\infty$ to have equality of mixed partial derivatives.

Comment: Ahhh I see!  Didn't know that, thanks!